# Sync an iOS app that uses core data to cloud

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm, cloudkit

I have written an app with Swift 2 using Core Data for persistence.  I am thinking about adding a feature to also persist in the cloud.  I have read tutorials on Realm and CloudKit, but haven't seen great examples on using them on top of (or along with) Core Data.

I want to:

1. allow users to enter their data once and have it appear on all their devices.
2. let users sync some of their data with a user of their choice.

Can I keep all my Core Data logic and simply add some server calls during CRUD operations using CloudKit (or some other framework)?  For example, I use `NSFetchedResultsController` for several of my tables, does it make sense to continue to use it while using CloudKit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`CloudKit` and `CoreData` do not automatically work together seamlessly, so you will need to write that logic yourself.

There are [different types of iCloud storage options](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH1-SW1), one or two of which do seamlessly integrate with `CoreData`, but `CloudKit` is not one of them, and `CloudKit` is what you will need to use if you have aspirations of enabling your users to share data with others.

**AKA:** You will need to do the heavy lifting yourself, but if you use good design practices you can do the work once without having to rewrite much of your existing code.

So, here's something similar to what I did in one of my projects that used both frameworks:

- Create Core Data object model and `NSManagedObject` subclasses like you almost certainly already have.
- Turn on CloudKit in Xcode project capabilities and log in to CloudKit Dashboard
- Use CloudKit Dashboard to design your record model modeled after your Core Data entity model
- (Back in Xcode) Create methods somewhere (most conveniently as extensions to your `NSManagedObject` subclasses) that know how to create the given Core Data object from a `CKRecord`, and to create a `CKRecord` from a Core Data object.
- Create one or more Swift classes dedicated to dealing with your CloudKit records and synching them with Core Data. This class(es) would be responsible for performing all CloudKit operations at a high level, including fetching, adding, deleting, modifying, etc. You can design this public API however you want (it should be customized to your needs), but this class would most likely use the methods you created in the previous step to convert to and from Core Data types.

With this approach, your CloudKit specializing class (we'll call it `CloudBrain`) does all of the heavy lifting, and if you want you can make it do it all behind the scenes. For example, you could define another class, `SyncBrain`, that would automatically listen for changes in the Core Data managed object context, and call corresponding methods on `CloudBrain` to ensure all changes are being kept in sync with iCloud. It would also need to do the reverse, listening for changes in iCloud and applying them to Core Data. This will of course require fetching changes initially from `CloudBrain` and you'll also want to look into `CKSubscription` for real-time updates.

The beauty of this approach is that if you set up all of that correctly, you can keep all of your other code the same, because every time your other classes interact with Core Data, `SyncBrain` automatically ensures that all changes in Core Data are reflected in iCloud and vice versa.

As for sharing with other users, this feature is new in iOS 10 and it does not appear as though Apple has yet updated the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH1-SW1). You should therefore watch [What's New with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/) from WWDC this year.

**Important Note:** When designing your record model in CloudKit Dashboard, be sure to follow the [iCloud Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH9-SW1) and not have parent record types with fields holding arrays of a child record type. This is not great performance. Instead, define the child record type to have a single `CKReference` field that points to its parent. That way if you need the children for a parent, you can just create a query that requests all objects with their parent set to the parent you want (as opposed to having to wait for all of the children to download when all you wanted was the parent).

Here are some WWDC sessions. Older sessions still contain very useful information but some of it is out of date.

- 2014 – [Introducing CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/208/) (A must-watch to get the concepts correct)
- 2014 – [Advanced CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/231/)
- 2015 – [What's New in CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/704/)
- 2015 – [CloudKit Tips and Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/715/)
- 2016 – [What's New with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/)
- 2016 – [CloudKit Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231/)

Comment: That's really helpful thanks.  I will probably go that route.  Will I need to write my own logic and keep track of "dirty" data?  For example, if a user inputs data on device A at time T, then opens the app on device B where it's last update was at time T-1, then do a pull from iCloud for all inputs after T-1?

Comment: @Coder1224 CloudKit has built-in support for change tags which will help you with some things, but you'll need to handle things like data being out-of-sync since every app can choose to handle it differently. Watching a few of the CloudKit WWDC sessions from 2014, 2015, and 2016 would likely be beneficial in this area. I'll update my post with some links.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I actually watched all of them.  They all have useful things in them, and I agree the 1st is a must.  They all make mention of caching things locally which of course I am using Core Data.  Do you think it's fine that I keep ALL the data locally?  I didn't see any of the WWDC talks address that.  I imagine I will make plenty of use of "change tags" and `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation`

Comment: @Coder1224 Storing all data locally as well is probably a good idea so that the user can still access everything offline. `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is also a good thing to use, but in my experience I've had trouble getting CloudKit to accurately return all changes.

Comment: I've made some good progress getting things working.  I have been able to add/update/delete in iCloud when my Core Data objects are added/updated/deleted.  I am running into the issue of what to do when a user does a delete, for example, while offline?  I was considering adding an addedQueue, modifiedQueue, and deletedQueue, and persisting them using `NSCoding`/`NSKeyedArchiver` and then try to dequeue them in the background or once every app launch.  Does that sound reasonable?  What was your experience with this problem?

Comment: The reason the solution I posted is only "similar" to what I have done (and why I had to build upon it in my answer) is because my iOS app basically only demanded read-only capability from the public database while an admin website was responsible for the addition and mutation of data. I therefore haven't had to deal with this problem but I'm sure there are lots of others who have. If online sources are not readily available for that, I would recommend creating a new question specific to this topic.

Comment: I posted it as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292321/cloudkit-what-to-do-when-a-user-adds-modifies-or-deletes-an-object-while-offl

Comment: Looks like `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordchangesoperation

Comment: Yes, this year's WWDC session introduced new ways for doing this, but I haven't personally used the new objects because I no longer manage the CloudKit app I worked on. Forgot about that when I posted my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 11, you can now mirror Core Data to the cloud. It seems really easy to do as well.  You just need to use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` instead of `NSPersistentContainer`.  Your data will sync with CloudKit automatically.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit) for more information.

PS. As of writing this, this is in beta.

Comment: Do you know if the new  NSPersistentCloudKitContainer will work for sharing data with others, not just between a single user's devices (CKShare) ?

Comment: @Rob I had the same question. The new syncing possibilities are fantastic, but I need the ability to share data. Now, you _can_ access specific records by objectID using (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/3141668-record) and create a _CKShare_ out of it, *but*: if you have a lot of entities you want to share, you need them to have the same _parent record_ (otherwise you had to share each of them separately). And here is the critical problem: Apple's new automatic sync doesn't work with native CloudKit references, but with foreign keys..

Comment: Actually all my entities share a single parent record.  My app allows users to share a  "Store" and each "Store" has "Products", "Employees", "Sales Receipts" etc... for example.  But, they all point back to a parent "Store"; so when the users shares a "Store" they get all the subordinate entities.  But I still don't think this will work because Apple maintains a custom Zone in the private database. Since records get saved in the private database, my thought is that CKShares would not be available, but hopefully I am wrong.

Comment: > Your data will sync with CloudKit automatically, in THEORY.